# error during process creation C:\Masm32\bin\ML.EXE /c /Cp /nologo /I"C:\Masm32\Include" "Hello.asm"

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I've just got started with RadASM as my assembly IDE.
I took some of their template projects of hello world and I just get compile it.
the code looks like:

```
assume  cs:cseg,ds:dseg,ss:sseg

cseg    segment

start:
    mov ax, dseg
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, offset msg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

 cseg   ends

dseg    segment byte

msg db  'Hello!',0Dh,0Ah,'$'
dseg    ends

sseg    segment stack

    db  100h dup(?)

sseg    ends

end start
```

when trying to compile it using make->build on the tool bar, the following error is displayed :

error during process creation
C:\Masm32\bin\ML.EXE /c /Cp /nologo /I"C:\Masm32\Include" "Hello.asm"

the path C:\Masm32\bin\ML.EXE does not exists.

Does anyone know this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [MASM32 SDK](http://www.masm32.com/) and install it, but you will not succeed in assembling this code. You're trying to build a 16-bit MSDOS program, while MASM32 by default handles 32-bit Windows sources. Besides, it probably won't work in your windows. Try another project.

Comment: All you need is the 16 bit linker and add it MASM32 and youcan assemble and link 16-bit code. I have a copy for download from my site: http://www.capp-sysware.com/downloads/link16.exe

Comment: @MichaelPetch: A 16-bit linker (link16.exe) is included in the MASM32 package. RadASM has instructions on how to integrate DOSLNK.EXE into the system. There remains the problem of the probably missing executability in 64-bit Windows. I think the OP loses the desire if they has to install and set up DOSBox and has to struggle through Ralph Brown's interrupt list. I completely disregarded the sense of such an undertaking.